# How do I remove spaces from shell variables?

Tags: shell, command-line, tr

I have done the following at command line:

```
$ text="name with space"
$ echo $text
name with space
```

I am trying to use `tr -d ' '` to remove the spaces and have a result of:

```
namewithspace
```

I've tried a few things like:

```
text=echo $text | tr -d ' '
```

No luck so far so hopefully you wonderful folk can help!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Bash, you can use Bash's built in string manipulation.  In this case, you can do:

```
> text="some text with spaces"
> echo "${text// /}"
sometextwithspaces
```

For more on the string manipulation operators, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

However, your original strategy would also work, your syntax is just a bit off:

```
> text2=$(echo $text | tr -d ' ')
> echo $text2
sometextwithspaces
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that, was in a tr mood working on this! Great answer as well!

Answer (score 11):

You don't need `echo` command at all, just use [Here String](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) instead:

```
text=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$text")
```

Just for curiosity I checked how much time such a trivial task takes for different tools. Here are the results sorted from slowest to fastest:

```
abc="some text with spaces"

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=$(echo $abc | tr -d ' '); done)
0.76s user 1.85s system 52% cpu 4.976 total

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=$(awk 'gsub(" ","")' <<< $abc); done)
1.09s user 2.69s system 88% cpu 4.255 total

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=$(awk '$1=$1' OFS="" <<< $abc); done)
1.02s user 1.75s system 69% cpu 3.968 total

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=$(sed 's/ //g' <<< $abc); done)
0.85s user 1.95s system 76% cpu 3.678 total

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=$(tr -d ' ' <<< $abc); done)
0.73s user 2.04s system 85% cpu 3.244 total

$ time (for i in {1..1000}; do def=${abc// /}; done)
0.03s user 0.00s system 59% cpu 0.046 total
```

The pure shell operation is definitely the fastest what is not surprising, but what is really impressive that it is over 100 times faster then the slowest command!

Comment: That is not always true http://stackoverflow.com/q/14967299

Answer (score 7):

Just modify your text variable as below.

```
text=$(echo $text | tr -d ' ')
```

However, if we have control characters this might break. So, as per Kasperd's suggestion, we could have double quotes around it. So,

```
text="$(echo "$text" | tr -d ' ')"
```

will be a better version.

Comment: Wonderful! I was soooo close. As a noob I am pleased I was heading the right direction! Thank you for the fast response as well, as soon as I have waited 8 minutes I will submit this as the answer!

Comment: @user3347022, you are welcome :)

Comment: This is going to break if `$text` contains control characters, which would be interpreted by the shell. Better put some double-quotes in there: `text="$(echo "$text" | tr -d ' ')"`

Comment: @kasperd, thanks for mentioning it. I have incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sed 's. ..g' <<< $text
namewithspace
```

Answer (score 3):

a special case when you need for a variable that has a number:

sh:

```
typeset -i A=B #or
typeset -i A="   23232"
```

ksh:

```
typeset -n A=B #or
typeset -n A="   23232"
```